# Bluetooth Classic: Scan only specific devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently working on an application in which I need to scan the mobile devices which have my application installed through Bluetooth classic. I know there is a scan method for Bluetooth LE which accepts **APPLICATION_UUID**.
If anyone knows the method for BT Classic please share,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there no such method for BT Classic, but You can filter "scanned" devices by it's [Device Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html):

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
                BluetoothDevice btDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if(btDevice .getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass() == BluetoothClass.Device.<your_class>) {
                    // do your magic with filtered device
                }
            }
```

You also can check several devices class:

```
int deviceClass = btDevice .getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass()

if (deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_WEARABLE_HEADSET
                        || deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO
                        || deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE
                        and so on.
```